# seach for substring with minimum characters match pandas

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have 1st dataFrame with column 'X' as :

```
X
A468593-3
A697269-2
A561044-2
A239882 04
```

2nd dataFrame with column 'Y' as :

```
Y
000A561044          
000A872220
```

I would like to match the part of substrings from both columns with minimum no. of characters(example 7 chars only alphanumeric to be considered for matching. all special chars to be excluded).
so, my output DataFrame should be like this

```
X
A561044-2
```

Any possible solution would highly appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure whether column `Y` follows a rule. I provided two approaches. Does one of them help?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC and assuming that the first three values of `Y` start with `0`, you can slice `Y` by `[3:]` to remove the first three zero values. Then, you can join these values by `|`. Finally, you can create your mask using `contains` that checks whether a series contains a specified value (in your case you would have something like 'A|B' and check whether a value contains 'A' or 'B'). Then, this mask can be used to query your other data frame.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"X": ["A468593-3", "A697269-2", "A561044-2", "A239882 04"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Y": ["000A561044", "000A872220"]})

mask = df1["X"].str.contains(f'({"|".join(df2["Y"].str[3:])})')
df1.loc[mask]
```

Output:

```py
    X
2   A561044-2
```

If you have values in `Y` that do not start with three zeros, you can use this function to reduce your columns and remove all first `n` zeros.

```py
def remove_first_numerics(s):
  counter = 0
  while s[counter].isnumeric():
    counter +=1
  return s[counter:]

df_test = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["01Abd3Dc", "3Adv3Dc", "d31oVgZ", "10dZb1B", "CCcDx10"]})
df_test["A"].apply(lambda s: remove_first_numerics(s))
```

Output:

```py
0     Abd3Dc
1     Adv3Dc
2    d31oVgZ
3      dZb1B
4    CCcDx10
Name: A, dtype: object
```